# How do security settings in config.yml and security.yml relate?

Tags: security, symfony

I am trying to set up user and security management in a first test application of mine and I have come to be a bit lost as to what does what.

My setup thus far: Symfony 2.5, SonataUserBundle (and with it FOSUserBundle)

In my `app/config/config.yml`, I have the following settings that I make out to be relevant in terms of managing site security (most taken over from the setup instructions of the various bundles I included):

```
imports:
    - { resource: security.yml }

[...]

fos_user:
    firewall_name:  main

[...]

security:
    # FOSUserBundle config
    # cf. https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-4-configure-your-applications-securityyml
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
    # end of FOSUserBundle config

    access_control:
        # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Admin login page needs to be access without credential
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Secured part of the site
        # This config requires being logged for the whole site and having the admin role for the admin part.
        # Change these rules to adapt them to your needs
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN] }
        - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

My `app/config/security.yml` looks as follows:

```
security:

    # added with Sonata User Bundle
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
    # end

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        # added with Sonata User Bundle
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager
        # end

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        # added with Sonata User Bundle
        # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
        admin:
            pattern:            /admin(.*)
            context:            user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /admin/login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /admin/login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:
                path:           /admin/logout
            anonymous:          true

        # -> end custom configuration

        # default login area for standard users

        # This firewall is used to handle the public login area
        # This part is handled by the FOS User Bundle
        main:
            pattern:             /(.*)
            context:             user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:             true
            anonymous:          true
        # end

        default:
            anonymous: ~

    # Sonata
    acl:
        connection: default

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        SONATA:
            - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT  # if you are using acl then this line must be commented
```

Here are my questions:

### Precedence of configurations

Based on my understanding of the "patterns" of Symfony thus far, anything in `security.yml` is loaded first and would thus take precedence over any new definitions for identical parameters further down in my `config.yml`. **Is that correct?**

### Duplicate definitions

It seems to me that the following are defined twice, once in `security.yml`, once in `config.yml`:

- The provider for FOSUserBundle (different values, `fos_user.user_manager` and `fos_user.user_provider.username`)
- The encoder for FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface
- The pattern for the `main` firewall (`^/`vs. `.*`)

**Are these indeed defining the same? Is it safe to assume that in all these cases, only those settings defined in `security.yml` apply?**

### Best practices

**How should security-related definitions generally be divided between `security.yml` and `config.yml` (and other potential locations)?**

Comment: You should not have the same section(i.e. security:)  in two different files.  Remove the security: section from config.yml.  I suspect you may have put it in there when you configured the fos_user section and perhaps misunderstood the directions.

Comment: Alright. I believe to have seen something in some part of the Symfony documentation that hinted at it being OK to have configs in both places. But the notice on this parts appears to confirm your suggestion: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#basic-example-http-authentication

Comment: So this page is missleading users I guess: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/testing/http_authentication.html 
It suggests that we could override security in the config_test.yml :(

Answer (score 3):

As Cerad mentionned in a comment, you have the same section `security:` in both files.

Look at the start of the `app/config/config.yml` file:

```
imports:
    - { resource: security.yml }
```

This means that the `security.yml` file will be imported when the `config.yml` file will be parsed by Symfony2. So you can keep only the `security:` section in the `app/config/security.yml` file in order to define the security configuration.

This is the default configuration, see these files in the official GitHub repository:

- [`app/config/config.yml`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/config/config.yml) (no `security:` section)
- [`app/config/security.yml`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/config/security.yml) (contains a `security:` section)